# Table <td> heigh increase when insert data

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have some simple table with standard HTML:

```
<table class="table datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Registrovaný</th>
            <th>Proces</th>
            <th>Stav</th>
            <th>Meno</th>
            <th>Poznámka</th>                                                
            <th>Anglicky</th>
            <th>Nemecky</th>
            <th>Uplatnenie</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Mesto</th>
            <th>Akcia</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>   
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Text3</td>
            <td>Text3</td>
            <td>Text3</td>
            <td>Text3</td>
            <td>Text3</td>
            <td>Text3</td>
            <td>Text3</td>
            <td>študent,právna asistentka, recepčná,právnik, advokátny koncipient, exekutórsky koncipient, notársky koncipient, advokát</td>
            <td>Text3</td>
            <td>Text3</td>
       </tr> 

    </table>
```

As you can see table is regular, but however if I try to insert some longer string between `<td>` I have problem because it make whole `<tr>` with bigger height.

I want to find some way how to display just part of it in HTML or find a way how to display it all in SINGLE LINE instead of multiple lines.

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/5n9se0kb/

Comment: do you want like this? https://jsfiddle.net/5n9se0kb/1/

Comment: Try:  td{white-space:nowrap;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a maximum height to the td, like `td { max-height: 50px }` then use something like `td {overflow-y: scroll}`. Alternatively, `td {white-space: nowrap}` should do you justice.